# Image quality of Tamron 16–300mm vs Nikon 18–55mm and 55–300mm lenses

Tags: lens, nikon, tamron, superzoom

I have a Nikon D5100 with the [Nikon DX AF-S Nikkor 18–55mm f/3.5–5.6G VR](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/camera-lenses/20059/af-p-dx-nikkor-18-55mm-f%252f3.5-5.6g-vr.html) and [Nikon DX AF-S Nikkor 55–300mm f/4.5–5.6G ED VR](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product/camera-lenses/af-s-dx-nikkor-55-300mm-f%252f4.5-5.6g-ed-vr.html) lenses. I find the sharpness of the 55–300mm lens is significantly better, so use that whenever possible.

I am considering purchasing a Tamron 16–300mm lens. Can I expect the image quality in the Tamron at the 55–300 range to be at least as good as my current 55–300 lens? And can I expect the image quality of the Tamron in the 18–55 range to be better than my current 18–55 lens?

Comment: My 18-55 lens is a Nikon DX AF-S Nikkor 18-55mm 1:3.5-5.6 G.  The 55-300 is a Nikon DX AF-S Nikkor 55-300mm 1:4.5-5.6 GED.  Both have vibration reduction (VR)  And yes, I guess there would be 2 questions there as you mentioned.  How does the Tamron compare to my kit lens in the 18-55 range and how does it compare to my 55-300 in the 55-300 range.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not a Nikon shooter so I'm not going to do your legwork for you, but I'd bet money the results are similar to [this comparison between the Canon EF-S 55-250, EF-S 18-200, and Sigma 18-250](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/38744/15871)

Comment: Related: [Is there any reason to choose the Canon 18-55 over the 18-135?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/95021/15871)

Comment: Not asking anybody to do my leg work. I have done the leg work and have read the reviews and comparisons of the lenses I am considering.  Looking for someone who has experience with the lenses and can give me a point of reference against a lens I am familiar with since image quality is difficult to quantify.

Answer (score 3):

After reading various reviews, you've probably noticed that the *general consensus* is:

- **Super-zoom lenses compromise on image quality for increased Zoom Range.** They typically have reduced Max Aperture, Sharpness, and Contrast. They typically have increased Chromatic Aberration and Lens Distortion.
- **OEM lenses provide better image quality than third party lenses.**

Based on this, the Tamron 16-300mm is at a disadvantage because it is a third-party lens with a greater zoom range. Although each lens should be considered for its own merits, **reviews of super zooms are *all* the same.**

> The _____ has good center sharpness *for the class*. However, the impressive zoom range comes at the cost of some noticeable softening and chromatic aberration, especially in the corners and at the long telephoto range. *For this type of lens,* distortion is mild at the wide and telephoto ends... <sup><sub>(Not a real review. For illustration only.)</sub></sup>

So **it's helpful to visually compare test shots** to *decide for yourself* whether a lens is good enough for you:

- [Tamron 16-300mm vs Nikon 18-55mm](https://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/ISO-12233-Sample-Crops.aspx?Lens=953&Camera=736&Sample=0&FLI=2&API=2&LensComp=663&CameraComp=614&SampleComp=0&FLIComp=4&APIComp=1)
- [Tamron 16-300mm vs Nikon 55-300mm](https://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/ISO-12233-Sample-Crops.aspx?Lens=953&Camera=736&Sample=0&FLI=3&API=1&LensComp=735&CameraComp=614&SampleComp=0&FLIComp=1&APIComp=1)

Comment: +1. Though I feel like there's gotta be a pros/cons of a superzoom question around here with which all other q's like this can be closed as a dupe (and where your answer may fit as well)